# OpenCV: findContours(): how contours are ordered?

Tags: python, opencv

When we want to find the contours of a given image according to a certain threshold, we use the function [cv2.findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) which returns among other things, the list of contours (a Pythonic list of arrays representing contours of the picture).

Here is how to [use of the function](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html):

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

My question:

What is the order that OpenCV uses toorder the countours ?

I mean on which criterion it says this contour is in *position 0*, the other in *position 1*  and so on ?

I need this information because I want to know which contour I am dealing with in my program and why it is given this or that position.

Hope you won't close my question, I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand the question but from my understanding the Contour positions are based on the x and y pixel coordinates of the image which is what the returned vector list contain. So surely the criterion is they're position on the image. (Please consider this as a comment)

Comment: Thank you. But each contour may have a lot of pixels. So how can they ordered according to their position on the image ?

Comment: By using cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE you are representing a contour with the two end point instead of taking into account all the pixels inbetween. Please refeer to the link below- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html

Comment: Assuming you are using cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE yes that is correct

Comment: I accepted your answer because it reflects exactly the behavior I have in my program where I have lot of contours. When I draw them one by one `cv2.drawContours(image,contours,indice_of_contour,color,thickness)` I have a behavior that respects exactly what you said. That is why I believe your answer is right.